# Squish popup menu causes the tests to get stuck

Tags: qt, popup, menubar, squish

I'm writing squish tests for an application that uses a menu that pops up once the mouse hovers over it, this means when the tests are running the user has to keep moving the mouse over the menu for the tests to proceed. The app is written in QT. Anyone have any experience with this and a way around it??

Comment: What is you problem? You don't know how to move mouse cursor?

Comment: It means you have to sit in front of it while all the tests run, could take hours.

Comment: I think Squish designed in the way that no one should sit in front of it while it is running tests. What prevents you from moving mouse cursor with the script?

Comment: That was it man thanks, using a mix of snooze() and moveCursor() I got it. http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/4.2/rgs-squish.html

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar issues.
You can write a bash script look for and kill the processes.

For a system dialog in MAC, you could do something like this:

number = `ps aux | grep "[U]serNotificationCenter" | wc -l`

```
  if(number.to_i != 0)
    `killall "UserNotificationCenter"`
  end
```